# Access two classes using find_next_sibling with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm web-scraping pokemondb.net. I'm currently trying to get the text of their 'types', but i can only get the first one(if you know anything about Pokemon, some have two types, yada,yada...). I'm trying to use find_next_sibling, but i'm not sure if i'm doing so correctly. What can I change to retrieve both their types?

It's inside the block..

```
<td class="cell-icon">
<a class="type-icon type-grass" href="/type/grass">Grass</a><br> 
<a class="type-icon type-poison" href="/type/poison">Poison</a>
</td>
```

What I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://pokemondb.net/pokedex/all')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
dex = soup.find(id = 'pokedex')

pokes = (dex.find_all(class_='cell-name'))
types = (dex.find_all(class_='cell-icon'))

pokemon_names = [poke.find(class_ = 'ent-name').get_text() for poke in pokes]
pokemon_types1 = [type_.find(class_ = 'type-icon').get_text() for type_ in types]

pokemon_types2 = [pokemon_types1.find_next_sibling(class_ = 'type-icon').get_text() ]

print(pokemon_types2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to iterate your `types` object :

```
pokemon_types = [type_.get_text() for type_ in types]
print(pokemon_types)
```

But really you can just use [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) doing the parsing for you by specifying the `id` of the table using `read_html` :

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

r = requests.get("https://pokemondb.net/pokedex/all")

dex = pd.read_html(r.text, attrs = {'id': 'pokedex'})

print(dex)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with this line...

```
pokemon_types1 = [type_.find(class_ = 'type-icon').get_text() for type_ in types]
```

`find` gets the first item, but you want all types so you need `find_all`. This will then give you a big list of types and Pokemon and not tell you which type is for which Pokemon. Need to take a step back to solve that.

We want the Pokemon and the types assigned to them, so a single row of that tables worth of data. First, let's get the row...

```
rows = dex.find_all('tr')
```

Then each row contains the name and associated types for that Pokemon. We can then loop through all of the rows and grab that data. Full code for this for me is...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://pokemondb.net/pokedex/all')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
dex = soup.find(id = 'pokedex')

rows = dex.find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    pokes = (row.find_all(class_='cell-name'))
    types = (row.select('.cell-icon .type-icon'))
    pokemon_names = [poke.find(class_='ent-name').get_text() for poke in pokes]
    pokemon_types = [type_.get_text() for type_ in types]
    print(pokemon_names)
    print(pokemon_types)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are too many things wrong;

`pokemon_types1` object is an array, you should iterate these and do the operations on each item in that array. You can't use `.find_next_sibling` method on an `array` because `array` object doesn't have a method as `find_next_sibling`.

And also there is one more problem, you are trying to use `find_next_sibling` after you get the text in `pokemon_types1`. So it's not a BeautifulSoup element anymore, it's just a string.

You are also getting duplicate elements when you use `type_.find(class_ = 'type-icon').get_text()`

[image]

I suggest you to use something like that:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get('https://pokemondb.net/pokedex/all')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
dex = soup.find(id = 'pokedex').find("tbody")

rows = dex.find_all("tr")

poke_dex = {}

for row in rows:
    poke_name = row.find(class_ = "ent-name").get_text()
    poke_dex[poke_name] = {}
    poke_dex[poke_name]["types"] = [i.get_text() for i in row.find_all(class_ = 'type-icon')]

print(poke_dex)
```

**Output**

```
{'Abomasnow': {'types': ['Grass', 'Ice']},
 'Abra': {'types': ['Psychic']},
 'Absol': {'types': ['Dark']},
 'Accelgor': {'types': ['Bug']},
 'Aegislash': {'types': ['Steel', 'Ghost']},
 'Aerodactyl': {'types': ['Rock', 'Flying']},
 'Aggron': {'types': ['Steel']},
 'Aipom': {'types': ['Normal']},
 'Alakazam': {'types': ['Psychic']},
 'Alcremie': {'types': ['Fairy']},
 'Alomomola': {'types': ['Water']},
 'Altaria': {'types': ['Dragon', 'Fairy']},
 'Amaura': {'types': ['Rock', 'Ice']},
 'Ambipom': {'types': ['Normal']},
 'Amoonguss': {'types': ['Grass', 'Poison']},
 'Ampharos': {'types': ['Electric', 'Dragon']},
 'Anorith': {'types': ['Rock', 'Bug']},
 .
 .
 .
 .
```

After that, you can import it to pandas, sorry I have no experience with pandas so I can't give you example to show how it's done.

Comment: hi there good day dear Guven - i want to re-run your answer-example-code and i get back on a freshly installed ATOM on Win 10 the following   ´File "C:\Users\Kasper\Documents\_mk_\_dev_\python\_examples_\panda.py", line 17
    print(poke_dex)from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.214s]´

what goes wrong here

Comment: Are you sure the line 17 is not `print(poke_dex)from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`?